# Missing CoreAudio process in Activity Monitor

Tags: macos, audio, activity-monitor

I have always had the buzzing audio issue that comes with the 2018 MacBook Pro Models *(I'm still convinced its an audio buffer size mismatch error)*. Up until now, I have always used the Kill CoreAudio in Activity Monitor trick to reset the audio and stop the buzzing.

Recently I have discovered that the CoreAudio has actually gone from my Activity Monitor! I still have audio and still have the buzzing issue. I'm just concerned that something will trip up along the ways because the CoreAudio is missing? Can someone shed some light on how to get it back please?

[image: Not found when searching "Core"]

[image: Not found when searching "Audio"]

Comment: coreaudio doesn't run under 'My Processes'. Check again under 'All Processes' in the View menu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The process `coreaudiod` runs under the system user `_coreaudiod`, not your own user. Activity Monitor in your screenshots has been filtered by processes running under your user, denoted by the ‘My Processes’ title. Choose View → All Processes to remove this filter, then your search for the process will return it.

[image]